# Nginx redirect users from / to index.php

Tags: nginx

I need rewrite users from root to index.php because now in google analytics I see 2 lines:

```
/            .............  112 
/index.php   .............  34
```

How I can redirect users who open http://example.com and http://example.com/   to http://example.com/index.php 
?

Comment: see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index

Answer (score 0):

This way working for me:

```
location = / {
    return 301  /index.php;
}
```